# SSL: match private key with certificate using PHP (without phpseclib)

Tags: php, ssl

I have tried to use this PHP code script to check SSL private key with SSL certificate match or not the result is match every time.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

if (!extension_loaded('OpenSSL')) {
        $this->markTestSkipped("Need OpenSSL extension");
}

$pkey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDvwT54v2kQTRP3
ZnJepfuBgEUfrEqBZ7zLm87s1NHwwJNNbwqGCYTIoCv4xDgRCK7X7NVmMyV2OWIn
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

$cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGRTCCBS2gAwIBAgIQVWcnF+whEw+mvnBlp/JMCzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB
kDELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

$check_result = check_pkey_cert_match($pkey, $cert);

if($check_result == true) {
  echo "Match";
} else {
  echo "Not Match";
}
```

this function use openssl by shell_exec it can export files server.crt, server.key, server.csr

```
function check_pkey_cert_match($Private_Key, $Certificate) {
  //checks if Private Key match Certificate

  $random_blurp = rand(10,99999);
  $tmp_dir = "/tmp/";

  if(openssl_x509_export_to_file($Certificate, $tmp_dir.$random_blurp.'.server.crt')) {
     echo "Export Cert OK = ".$tmp_dir.$random_blurp.".server.crt";
  } else {
    echo "Export Crt Error";
  }

  if(openssl_pkey_export_to_file($Private_Key, $tmp_dir.$random_blurp.'.server.key')) {
     echo "Export Pkey OK = ".$tmp_dir.$random_blurp.".server.key";
  } else {
     echo "Export Pkey Error";
  }
```

but when i use this shell_exec for check $pkey_check & $cert_check match or not it still result match every time. Because $pkey_check & $cert_check = null

```
  $pkey_check = shell_exec('openssl pkey  -in 
'.$tmp_dir.$random_blurp.'.server.key -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum');

  $cert_check = shell_exec('openssl x509  -in 
'.$tmp_dir.$random_blurp.'.server.crt  -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum');

 // $csr_check = shell_exec('openssl req -in '.$tmp_dir.$random_blurp.'.server.csr -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum');


  //remove those temp files.

  unlink($tmp_dir.'server.crt');

  unlink($tmp_dir.'server_key');

  //unlink($tmp_dir.'server.csr');

  //Check for match

  if ( $cert_check == $pkey_check ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

Result of above script

Export Cert OK = /tmp/41893.server.crt

Export Pkey OK = /tmp/41893.server.key

cert_check =

pkey_check =

Match

I have try another shell_exec but the same resutl

```
  /*
  $pkey_check = shell_exec('openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in  server.key | openssl md5');
  $cert_check = shell_exec('openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.crt | openssl md5');
  $csr_check = shell_exec('openssl req -noout -modulus -in  server.csr | openssl md5');
  */

  /*  
  $pkey_check = shell_exec('openssl rsa  -modulus -in '.$tmp_dir.$random_blurp.'.server.key | openssl md5 2>&1');
  $cert_check = shell_exec('openssl x509  -modulus -in '.$tmp_dir.$random_blurp.'.server.crt | openssl md5 2>&1');
  $csr_check = shell_exec('openssl req -noout -modulus -in '.$tmp_dir.$random_blurp.'.server.csr | openssl md5 2>&1');
  */

  $pkey_check = shell_exec('openssl pkey  -in '.$tmp_dir.$random_blurp.'.server.key -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum');
  $cert_check = shell_exec('openssl x509  -in '.$tmp_dir.$random_blurp.'.server.crt  -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum');
 // $csr_check = shell_exec('openssl req -in '.$tmp_dir.$random_blurp.'.server.csr -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

This simple script use to check private key & certificate match or not.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

if (!extension_loaded('OpenSSL')) {
        $this->markTestSkipped("Need OpenSSL extension");
}
```

Define $cert and $pkey (or use $_POST[$cert] and $_POST[$pkey] instead)

```
$pkey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDvwT54v2kQTRP3
ZnJepfuBgEUfrEqBZ7zLm87s1NHwwJNNbwqGCYTIoCv4xDgRCK7X7NVmMyV2OWIn
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

$cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGRTCCBS2gAwIBAgIQVWcnF+whEw+mvnBlp/JMCzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB
kDELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

Call function check_pkey_cert_match() and result.

```
$check_result = check_pkey_cert_match($pkey, $cert);

if($check_result == true) {
  echo "Match";
} else {
  echo "Not Match";
}
```

Just use Function openssl_x509_check_private_key()

```
function check_pkey_cert_match($Private_Key, $Certificate) {

  //Check for match
  if(openssl_x509_check_private_key ( $Certificate , $Private_Key )) {
      return true;
  } else {
     return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: @Jakkrit: interesting, but once people add their private key to that to test it, it is no longer private, and they'd have to regenerate it.

Comment: @JakkritHochoey: please remove that. I don't wish to be associated with your project, sorry. Please note that it is common (and expected) to ask people for permission before using their name in some way, especially since doing so may constitute endorsement.